# Google Maps distance server-side

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, google-maps

I've used Google Maps API in Javascript many times, but now I need to get the distance between two addresses server-side, and I can't find good documentation on how to achieve this.

I found this: [Google Maps APIs > Web Services > Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

But I'm not convinced that it's up to the task or how to use it.

I need the distance `by car`, for example travelling between these two addresses should result `22.4 km`.

From

`Flemmingvej 22, 8762 Flemming, Danmark`

To

`Ormedamsvej 3, 8660 Skanderborg, Danmark`

This would be easy for me in Javascript. But Server-side in a `Winforms` project (VB.NET or C#)... not so much `:-/`

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the right service to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) is the indicated API for the job as it

> provides travel distance and time for a matrix of origins and destinations, based on the recommended route between start and end points

You need to query it through HTTP and you will get a JSON or XML response so you can use it in your VB.NET, C# or whatever language you want if you write and perform the HTTP request and manage the XML or JSON result.

You can pass several optional parameters to refine your query (for example, `mode` will let you specify the mode of transport, with `driving` as default).

There are also [Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library) that you can use to query the service (currently Java, Python, Go and Node.js).

Comment: Okay, I did think it seemed like the proper choice. Thanks for confirming this.